# How can I properly watch psql command?

Tags: linux, macos, unix, psql, watch

## Seed

I seed my database

```
curl -s http://site/api/seed/user/1000
```

---

## Test

I did

```
psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27 -c "SELECT count(*) from users;"
```

I got

```
 count                                                                                                                                                                                 
-------                                                                                                                                                                                
  1000                                                                                                                                                                                 
(1 row)
```

## Watch

```
watch psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27 -c "SELECT count(*) from users;"
```

I got

```
Every 2.0s: psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27 -...  bh-macbook-pro-15-512gb.local: Tue Nov 21 15:19:08 2017

sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('                                                                         
sh: -c: line 0: `psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27 -c SELECT count(*) from users;'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: I hate when people downvote other people post without saying anything in the comment for the OP to improve it.

Comment: What is `watch`?

Comment: `watch` will rerun same command every 1 second.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `watch`, it's not re-quoting the arguments.

Comment: In this case, I want to see if my seed command working and not hang. `watch` command will show the incremental count of my table in my database.

Comment: `watch` is not a standard OS X command (it's not in El Capitan, at least).

Comment: @Barmar I thought so too. I've tried single quote, double quote, no quote -- nothing working.

Comment: @Barmar : I just install it via **brew**

Comment: Unless, **watch** in Mac is different than **watch** in Linux.

Answer (score 10):

Provide the command as a single, quoted argument:

```
watch 'psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27 -c "SELECT count(*) from users;"'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use the commande `\watch` of psql

##### One line in terminal

To **run everything** in **one command** in your terminal, **echo your SQL QUERY** with the **addition `\watch`** at the end and **use the pipe `|` to provide your psql command**.
*If you use the psql command with the argument `-c` the `\watch` command will not work (the `-c` necessarily ends with a semicolon `;` and therefore the command `\watch;` is not recognized).*

```bash
echo 'YOUR_SQL_QUERY; \watch' | psql [your_connection]
```

Example:

```bash
echo 'SELECT count(*) from users; \watch' | psql --username=nm -d portal -h 192.168.1.27
```

##### Interactive terminal

To execute the command directly on **PostgreSQL interactive terminal of [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-psql.html)**, once connected to your database, execute your command and then **use the `\watch` command**. Example:

```sql
SELECT count(*) from users;
\watch
```

##### Description of the commande `\watch`:

```sql
\watch [ i[nterval]=seconds ] [ c[ount]=times ] [ seconds ]
```

> Repeatedly execute the current query buffer (as \g does) until interrupted,or the query fails, or the execution count limit (if given) is reached. Wait the specified number of seconds (default 2) between executions. For backwards compatibility, seconds can be specified with or without an interval= prefix. Each query result is displayed with a header that includes the \pset title string (if any), the time as of query start, and the delay interval.

source: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-WATCH